# spring boot resttemplate api call by passing username and password

Tags: rest, spring-boot, spring-security, resttemplate

i want get data from rest api .. in backend iam using spring boot  RestInterceptor

> Error--<302,[Location:"/TicketingSystem/Index.html",
>   Content-Length:"0", Date:"Tue, 19 Nov 2019 
>             11:07:00 GMT"]>

Comment: try to print `result.getBody()` and provide entire stack of your error.

Comment: Make sure **http://localhost:9090/TicketingSystem/caselogcontroller/getAppIds** is up and running. Secondly It is Post Request while you are providing request body as null. Exception might thrown due to that